# What's an easy to use API for plotting latitude/longitude pairs on a world map?

Tags: python, perl, geolocation, gis

I have a list of 50000 latitude/longitude pairs and want to plot them on a map. I tried http://gsl-nagoya-u.net/appendix/software/worldmap/. It works but it seems to ignore the data after a certain point (less than 100). What else can I use to generate a static image? I'd rather not use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Perl has [GD::Map](http://p3rl.org/GD%3a%3aMap) in CPAN which looks about right.  I haven't used it myself to say for sure, but its the closest thing I could find based on your requirements.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try. Hopefully it can handle large amounts of data.

Comment: Way too resource intensive to even create a basemap without any data. It ran for 15 minutes and then I killed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [google maps static image api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), it has a 1000 images/day limit, but you could get it in <s>5</s> 50 days. Script the creation of the links and save the resulting image.

Edit: Looks like I misread your total number of pairs. 50 days is quite a long time, perhaps there is some way to avoid this, otherwise maybe this won't be preferred.

Comment: I need them all plotted on the same image anyway, not 50000 separate images.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [MapServer](http://www.mapserver.org/). It's more of a complete GIS platform, so if you only need to do this one time, it is a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else would have to tell you where to get baselayers, but you can render reasonable maps with [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).